# How to solve 500 Server Error in a laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

i got 500 Server Error when I run my laravel project, how can I solve this?

I already tried composer update and updating my env. but still error 500 keeps appearing. How can I solve this? I am just learning laravel so bear with me, I am not a pro, sorry.

Comment: Check the php error log for a more detailed error message. Or failing that check the Apache log

Comment: With Laravel and if you are developing locally (and only when you are developing locally) make sure `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file so you can see the exception detail and stack trace rather than a generic 500 error.

Comment: Pls have a look at the log files within storage/logs folder.